# AWS SQS groups in FIFO queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

So from the SQS documentation, consumer can be scaled horizontally, if group -ids are added to messages. I assume that these group-ids are dynamic.

If a consumer is initially handling messages of group-id `A` and `B`, and a big inflow of A comes in, would messages of group B be automatically routed to another consumer if no messages of type B are currently in-flight ?  How is the consumer client routing determined, is it dynamic, or a fixed hash ? eg: if new group-ids are added is it ensured that the load is distributed evenly across consumers ?

Is there a way to get group-wise counts of the queue size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "consumer client routing" in Amazon SQS.

Rather, consumers are responsible for asking the SQS queue for messages.

It is *your* responsibility to scale and balance the clients appropriately.

From [Avoid having a large backlog of messages with the same message group ID - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html):

> For FIFO queues, there can be a maximum of 20,000 inflight messages (received from a queue by a consumer, but not yet deleted from the queue). If you reach this quota, Amazon SQS returns no error messages. If your queue has a large backlog of 20,000 or more messages **with the same message group ID**, FIFO queues might be unable to return the messages that have a different message group ID but were sent to the queue at a later time until you successfully consume the messages from the backlog.

This is only a problem if the messages are currently 'being processed'.

Comment: So, if we just add multiple consumers to the queue, messages from any group would be provided ? eg: violating the message-group-order ?

Comment: check this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-queues-understanding-logic 

This documentation says that groupIDs will be distributed across consumers (optimistically).

Comment: I fixed my response. When receiving messages, you cannot request a specific `MessageGroupId`. Instead, the first message on the queue will be returned _unless_ a message with the same `MessageGroupId` is currently being processed. There is a risk that the 'in flight' message might be returned to the queue if it fails to process, so it is not possible to process another message with the same `MessageGroupId` until that message has finished processing. Thus, it will give you the first message(s) in the queue that does not have a `MessageGroupId` that is being processed.

Comment: So in my example the messages of type B will be routed to the other consumer right ?

Comment: Messages aren't "routed to consumers". Rather, consumers request messages. If one consumer is currently processing something from Message Group A, then the next request for a message will be provided with a message from Message Group B.

Answer (score 3):

It is your consumers which would be *requesting* messages from SQS.

If all messages are grouped, and a consumer takes a message from group `A`, all other messages from group `A` would be **invisible to the other consumers until the message is acknowledged (deleted) or reaches visibility timeout**. Therefore, on any other consumer's request, they will be given messages from other visible (unblocked) groups - in this case group `B` (as long as there are less than 20k messages for group `A` in the queue, as per documentation).

NB: In a FIFO grouped multi-consumer setup like this, I would suggest against **prefetching** more than 1 message per consumer. Let's say you have prefetch 10, and a consumer requests and gets 10 messages (from 10 different groups as explained above). My understanding is that this will block all 10 groups in this consumer's own prefetched "queue", and undermine the multi-consumer setup.

NB2: If you want to **reject** a message (eg. send it to deadletter), make sure to call the `ChangeMessageVisibility` to set it to 0, so it is rejected immediately. If not, SQS will be waiting until the queue visibility timeout is reached, blocking that group for the whole time it is waiting.